# ¿cómo puedo mostrar una imagen en una card que la imagen esté almacenada en firebase storage que haga la llamada y lo muestre. Trabajo con ionic 3

Tags: firebase, ionic, angular5, ionic3

Ejemplo de etiqueta de `HTML` y método correspondiente para seleccionar la imagen:

```js
function onUpload(e) {
  console.log('subir', e);
  const id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  const filePath = "event_upload/profile_${id}";
  const ref = this.storage.ref(filePath);
  const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <ion-input type="file" accept=".png, .jpg" (change)="onUpload"></ion-input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

no entiendo bien tu pregunta, primero que nada, veo que estás subiendo la imagen desde tu app a Firebase, pero creo que lo que intentas hacer es hacer cards dinámicas, para ello, solo debes de obtener la url de descarga que firebase te proporciona con getDownloadURL y la guardas en alguna variable, en este caso en downloadLink, luego, obtén el id de tu imagen, ej: , y le haces print a tu id con la función getElementById: document.getElementById("mi-imagen").src = downloadLink;